# SF Site couldn't retrieve data

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites, site.com

I created a VFPage and it works just fine. After that, I created a SF-Site "[Here is the link](http://hasan-developer-edition.eu2.force.com/AbuNawaf1)", and it worked fine, but after a couple hours it stopped and I get this error in the browser console:

> GET
> http://hasan-developer-edition.eu2.force.com/javascript/1417686327000/sfdc/source/main.js.map
> 503 (Service Unavailable)
> javascript/1417772649000/sfdc/source/VFState.js.map:1
>
> GET
> http://hasan-developer-edition.eu2.force.com/javascript/1417772649000/sfdc/source/VFState.js.map
> 503 (Service Unavailable)

And heres a screenshot:

[image]

---

And by the way, all my resources are public. So, any suggestions about this?

Comment: check whether you have given the object settings correctly or not...!

Comment: @Hasan, I am getting the same error. How did you resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

One thing to check is the "24-Hour Usage History" section of your site which is near the bottom of your "Site Details" page.

In developer edition orgs the daily limits are quite low:

- 500 MB "Origin Bandwidth"
- 10 Minutes "Request Time"

and I have certainly hit the latter limit when doing development work (though I don't remember if that resulted in a 503 error or not).

The good news is that in an enterprise edition production org these start out at 40 GB and 60 Hours respectively. See the "Sites Limits" section of the [Salesforce Limits Quick
Reference Guide](https://na3.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.pdf).

Comment: Hi @keith-c . Actually the used percentage is 1% for each. Is there anything else that could cause this ?

Comment: @HasanKhatib The link in your question works right now so it may be that the heavy usage was over 24 hours ago. I suggest you check those daily limit values should you start getting the error again. If you haven't changed anything and the problem just comes and goes I don't know what else might cause it.